# Passing boost::filesystem::path to boost::process::child causes exception on Windows

Tags: c++, boost-process

Example code below causes exception on Windows:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace boost::process;

int main()
{
  child child(exe = search_path("app", { current_path() / "app_dir" }),
              args = { "--help" });

  child.wait();

  return 0;
}
```

But this one is not:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace boost::process;

int main()
{
  child child(search_path("app", { current_path() / "app_dir" }).string(),
              "--help");

  child.wait();

  return 0;
}
```

This is the exception message:

```
boost codecvt to wchar_t: error
```

I found some information about codecvt in Boost documentation:

> Since windows does not use UTF-8 it is sometimes unavoidable to use
>   the wchar_t version of the WinApi. To keep this library consistent it
>   provides wchar_t support on posix also.
>
> Since the posix api is purely char every wchar_t based type will be
>   converted into char.
>
> Windows on the other hand is more selective; the default is to use
>   char, but if any parameter requires wchar_t, everything will be
>   converted to wchar_t. This also includes boost::filesystem::path.
>   Additionally, if the system does not provide the char api (as is the
>   case with Windows CE) everything will also be converted.

But I think that I am using child process properly in both cases. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this nasty behaviour on Win32 crop up when the user has a non-ASCII username (regardless of the path of the parent process).

Only safe solution I could find is to always pass the child path and all flags as wchar_t strings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).